# Помогите написать пользовательский скрипт-перенаправление

Tags: replace

Если в адресной строке https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=firefox чтобы автоматически перенаправляло на https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&q=firefox
Где firefox поисковый запрос, который может меняться. То есть, чтобы **#** менялось на **search?**

Вроде вот так работает

`window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('#', 'search?');`

URL меняется, но почему то идет постоянная перезагрузка страницы. Откуда она берется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Постоянная перезагрузка  страницы идет потому, что нужно Вы  используете `window.location.href`без проверки на необходимость использования.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var re = 'google.ru/#';
var arr = url.split(re);
if(arr.length > 1){
    window.location.href = arr[0] + 'google.ru/search?' + arr[1];
}
```

Comment: Тогда постоянное перенаправление https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&q=firefoxgoogle.ru/search?undefinedgoogle.ru/search?undefinedgoogle.ru/search?undefined

Comment: Да. Поменял arr.length > 1 тогда работает. Правда google наверное использует динамическую подгрузку, если кликать из живого поиска и там перенаправление не срабатывает. Только при переходе по обычным ссылкам или если самому обновить страницу. Но это уже другая проблема.

Comment: Я для чего все это затеял. Старая Opera 12 в современном дизайне гугл поиска перестала почему-то отображать результаты поиска, если в адресе присутствует # (а он по умолчанию) просто пустая страница. Однако с параметром search? еще работает. Вот я их хотел написать UserJS для перенаправления. Но с динамическим контентом сложнее. Не могли бы вы что-нибудь посоветовать на этот счет?

Comment: @Alex, вы видимо невнимательно прочитали вопрос: `URL меняется, но почему то идет постоянная перезагрузка страницы. Откуда она берется?`

Comment: @Visman из вопроса видим, что проблема в перенаправлении без проверки(нужно или нет), а в целом - информации мало в вопросе.

Comment: @Alex, так потому его и закрыли.